# VB6: How to remove the Time part from Date type

Tags: vb6, date-formatting

I have a `Date` variable which contains also the time:

```
Dim dt As Date
dt = "8/3/2016 7:10:40 AM"
```

--> remove somehow the time so the result should be:

```
dt = "8/3/2016"
```

How to remove the time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For another Date type variable:

```
dt = DateValue(dt)
```

or

```
dt = CDate(Int(dt))
```

Or for a *string*:

```
strdt = format$(dt, "m/d/yyyy")
```

Comment: `DateValue` is evil as it casts arg `dt` to `String`. `DateSerial` params are verbose but at least it's not "stringly" typed as `DateValue`

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim dateonly As String
dateonly = Left(dt, InStr(dt, " ")-1)
```

You can make it safer by adding a test :

```
Dim dt As String
Dim pos As Integer
Dim dateonly As String

dt = "8/6/2016"
pos = InStr(dt, " ")
If pos Then
    dateonly = Left(dt, pos - 1)
Else
    dateonly = dt
End If

Debug.Print dateonly
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your replay. I think that using DateValue is the best option.